# Method that passes two arrays in, compares the items, then returns the matches

Tags: c#, arrays, dictionary, linear-search

So I got posed with this question, and I initially wrote the answer to this returning a new array, using a nested for loop comparing the elements of the arrays and adding to the new array if they matched. I then was explained how this is inefficient and wouldn't work right. I don't know much about algorithms or data structures yet, and I was told that hashtables or dictionaries would be a better method of storing the matching data. I am attempting to figure this method out, and would love input or help on this. Thanks!

One of the things I don't understand about with Dictionaries is... with pretty much every example I've seen, the "key" is usually some string value, then the value is the number value represented by that string. In this case I only have two numeric values, the items in the two arrarys passed. since I would only add it to the dictionary if they are the same, do I say 1 item is the key and the other is the value? I am unsure. Does a dictionary account for duplicates?

```
public Dictionary<int, int> twoArrays(int[] x, int[] y)
{
    Dictionary<int, int> myDictionary = new Dictionary<int,int>();
    foreach (var item in x)
    {
        foreach (var item1 in y)
        {
            if (item == item1)
            {
                myDictionary.Add(item, item1);
            }
        }
    }
    return myDictionary;
}
```

Thanks for any and all help. I'm reading up on this as much as I can but sometimes your help/quick suggestions are more clear when I see the code.

Comment: Why do you actually want a dictionary here? It sounds like you should just be returning an array, which can be implemented with `return x.Intersect(y).ToArray();`...

Comment: @JonSkeet does .Intersect account for duplicates?

Comment: @jacksonSD: It depends on what you mean by "account for". The returned sequence is effectively a set, so it won't contain duplicates. It's unclear whether that's what you want or not.